# Python to call Excel macro - ActiveWorkbook

Tags: python, excel

I tried to use Python to call an Excel macro. The macro is to copy and rename the csv.

```
def run_macro (excel_name, module_name, macro_name):

    import win32com.client
    import os

    xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")  #instantiate excel app
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath(excel_name))
    print (module_name+'.'+macro_name)
    try:
        xl.Run(module_name+'.'+macro_name)
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
    wb.Save()
    xl.Application.Quit()
    del xl
    return

excel = 'D:\\WBCored\\macro.xlsm'
module = 'Module1'
macro = 'uploadnewdata()'
run_macro(excel, module, macro)
```

The Excel macro is:

```
Sub uploadnewdata()
    Workbooks.Open "D:\WBCored\Test1.csv"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("D:\WBCored\Test1_cpy.csv")
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

The Excel macro has been tested in Excel. But it is not working to use in Python. It seems not working with `ActiveWorkbook`. Is it true? I would like to change the Python code instead of the macro, as the original macro has many more lines. It is easier to call all the macros with Python, rather than moving the platform from Excel to Python. The code I quoted here is for demo purpose.
Any help?

Comment: Why do you need to run the `macro` instead of using `shutil.copy(src_file,dst_file)`?

Comment: @Marcelo, The job has lots of macros linking up together. It is easier to call all the macros instead of moving the platform from macro to Python. The case quoted is one of the problems facing only.

Comment: Unless you have the same macro in multiple modules, you don't need the module specifier. The variable `macro` should be `uploadnewdata`, **not** `uploadnewdata()`.

Comment: It works. 
`uploadnewdata` instead of `uploadnewdata()` makes the difference.